# Cronjob every x hours between 23-16 not working

Tags: cron

Partly using stackoverflow search I figured out how to run my cronjob every 3 hours but not between 23h-16h. That means a pause between 16h today untill 23h today. So the cronjob should start running every 3 hours at 23h and stop at 16h, then start again at 23h.

This is the result:

`0 23-16/3 * * * /usr/local/bin/flexget -c /media/usb/Downloads/flexget/config.yml --cron`

Now my question: Why is this not working? It does not run at all :(

I also tried:

`* 23-16/3 * * * /usr/local/bin/flexget -c /media/usb/Downloads/flexget/config.yml --cron`

(not sure what the difference is with 0 or with * for the minutes, rounded hours or not?)

This DOES work:

`0 */3 * * * /usr/local/bin/flexget -c /media/usb/Downloads/flexget/config.yml --cron`

But then it just runs every 3 hours every day, without pause between 16-23.

Answer (score 1):

You can always list the hours explicitly.

```
0 2,5,8,11,14,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/flexget -c /media/usb/Downloads/flexget/config.yml --cron
```

Note this is **not** the same as with replacing `0` minutes with `*`, like:

```
* 2,5,8,11,14,23 * * * /usr/local/bin/flexget -c /media/usb/Downloads/flexget/config.yml --cron
```

The latter starts on *every* minute on the hours specified, i.e. 2:00, 2:01, 2:02, ..., 2:59, 5:00, 5:01, ... 5:59, ...

Comment: OK thanks! 
Do wonder why 16-23 is not working. But I will use your solution!

Comment: because the 23 and the 16 are on different days. suppose you specify 23-16, and also the day-of-week=x or day-of-month=x. how can it know if you mean the 16:00 is on day x or the the 23:00?